# Ionic Framework Paypal plugin integration application crashed

Tags: cordova, paypal, ionic-framework

i am integrating paypal in ionic but after prepareToRender function App is getting stopped and crashed?

I am trying to use paypal sandox account and setting environment `PayPalEnvironmentSandbox`. When i use environment `PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork` then it's working.
i am using [paypal plugin](https://gist.github.com/Urbiwanus/c1e456f889f53e940a11)

```
function onPayPalMobileInit() {

                $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
                    // must be called
                    // use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork mode to get look and feel of the flow
                    PayPalMobile.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', configuration(), function () {
                      $timeout(function () {
                            init_defer.resolve();
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
```

Comment: where are you call app.initPaymentUI(); method

Comment: @ManishSingh i am using same thing but i am not able to call initPaymentUI(),inside my app.js , how to init, i used this link but i am not able to call PaypalService,https://gist.github.com/Urbiwanus/c1e456f889f53e940a11

Comment: Call initPaymentUI() method from controller. cut this method from app.js and paste it into you controller js file insider your function like  $scope.buyNow = function () {
                PaypalService.initPaymentUI().then(function () {
                    PaypalService.makePayment($scope.total, "Total").then();
                  
                });
            }

Comment: thanks manish , i successfuly integrated paypal but while executing at run time getting json error whike initializing paypal enviornment at line 41 cdv-plugin-paypal-mobile-sdk.js  help will be deeply appreciated